# Is it possible to change the connection time out setting for IIS in Azure App Services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an asp.net application hosted on a VM with IIS. Now I would like host the same application in Azure App Services. We had IIS settings modified like **Connection Time-out**.

How do set Connection Time-out value for Azure App Services

[image]

Comment: You could try with this extension [IISManager](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Site-Extensions#authoring-xdt-transforms) and add the limits.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/#configuration-sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to edit the `connectionTimeout` setting under `system.applicationHost`, you could modify the `applicationhost.config` file. You could create it manually or use [IISManager](https://github.com/shibayan/IISManager) to create the file and modify it.

Here is the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/#configuration-sample):

```
<system.applicationHost>
   <sites>
      <siteDefaults>
         <logFile logFormat="W3C"
            directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles"
            enabled="true" />
         <traceFailedRequestsLogging enabled="true"
            directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles"
            maxLogFiles="20" />
         <limits connectionTimeout="00:01:00" />
         <ftpServer serverAutoStart="true" />
         <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="127.0.0.1:8080:" />
         </bindings>
      </siteDefaults>
   </sites>
</system.applicationHost>
```